# Interaction between mousePressEvent and paintEvent methods

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

There are two methods in source code which must interact between them.

The first method is:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        event = QtGui.QMouseEvent(QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress, event.pos(), QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
        centerX = event.pos().x()
        centerY = event.pos().y()
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.mousePressEvent(self, event)
```

And the second method is:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
    painter.drawEllipse(centerX, centerY, 110, 110)
    QtWidgets.QMainWindow.paintEvent(self, event)
```

The sense of this program is: when I press by left mouse button on the main window a circle must appear.

First I press left mouse button therefore **QMouseEvent** takes place then **QPaintEvent** appears.

From that I do not know where calling **paintEvent()** method must be located inside of **mousePressEvent()** method hence this program does not work.

When I try to insert calling **paintEvent()** method inside of **mousePressEvent()** method I receive error message.

Tell me, please, when must I insert calling **paintEvent()** method inside **mousePressEvent()** method?

Thank You!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `update()`, this method calls the `paintEvent` function. In addition the variables `centerX` and `centerY` must be attributes of the class, but a better option is to use the position as input (`self.center`) and to verify that it has been used.

Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.center = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            event = QtGui.QMouseEvent(QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress, event.pos(), QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
            self.center = event.pos()
            self.update()
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.center: 
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
            painter.drawEllipse(self.center, 110, 110)
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.paintEvent(self, event)


import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank You @eyllanesc for the answer.

Comment: Yes, I did. I inserted `self.update()` string, which You had mentioned, in the `mousePressEvent()` method body after the `if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton` string to perform the `QMainWindow` update directly after the left mouse button click. Thank You, @eyllanesc. –